Transfer switch "inline" to well pump as opposed to vicinity of breaker panel
I'm looking to install a generator transfer switch to power the well pump as needed. The question I have comes in due to an unorthodox setup - the breaker for the well pump is in the main panel in the cabin, but the disconnect and well itself are about 70ft away in a pumphouse. Also happens to be adjacent to our propane tank (propane genny) and has a lean-to that works nicely to cover the generator in inclement weather. So my question is: can I wire a transfer switch "inline" at the pump house as opposed to powering the main panel? Seems like I could, but main concern is that the breaker would then be "upstream".. would I need another breaker in between the switch and disconnect for when on generator power? Any insight greatly appreciated!

Is the generator only for the pump?   What is the pump's breaker size, and its rated power, and what breakers are available on the generator?  A lot of portable generators have 15 and 20 amp outlets with suitable breakers in addition to their larger outlets -- does yours?

There are some issues with grounding with a portable generator, that are especially important here, and different from the typical case of plugging into your main breaker panel, and that are beyond by ability to answer but I think worth asking.  Perhaps in a new question once you know your approach and you also know if your generator is bonded or not or adaptable.

Is your generator a portable unit or permanently mounted, and are you intending this transfer function to be manual or automatic?

Subpanel to the Rescue
Since you only have one circuit, all you need near the pump is a disconnect. However, there is no reason you can't have a subpanel as the disconnect. For example, you could install an 8 space subpanel like this Eaton BR selected from Home Depot for illustration purposes:


Two spaces will hold a breaker connected to the feed from the main panel.
Two spaces will hold a breaker connected to the generator.
Two spaces will hold the pump breaker.
Two spaces are available if you would like to use them for wiring up convenience receptacles and lighting.

You then install a generator interlock that fits around the first two double-breakers, allowing one at a time to be ON.
No fancy switch needed. When power goes out:

Turn off the utility breaker.
Slide the interlock.
Turn on the generator breaker.
Start the generator.

(There may be reasons to flip the last two steps, consult your generator manual or ask for more details.)
The total cost is pretty low *, and you get the bonus of extra circuits for other uses.
* You may find that a generator interlock that consists of a couple of small pieces of metal and a few screws costs nearly as much, possibly more than, an entire subpanel with case, busbars, etc. But that happens because a lot more subpanels are sold than interlocks, and if you need the interlock you NEED the interlock so you pay the price.
